# Moving a web app from default root to new context root

Tags: java, apache, jsp, mod-rewrite, jboss

We have a large legacy application that currently has the default context root of "/" running on resin pro. We are moving to clustered JBoss w/ Apache/mod_cluster and found that we need to have a context root that is not ROOT ("/"). Is there an easy way to refactor the application without changing thousands of links, images, css, js, and jsp references? mod_rewrite is available, but we are having trouble getting it to work.

Example:
Old login page was /webfront/login.jsp
New login page with context root will be /web/webfront/login.jsp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this could work

`RewriteRule ^/webfront/(.*) /web/webfront/$2 [R]`

Comment: Thank you Pablo. This will need to be applied site-wide, and not to just the webfront directory. It will need to apply to all images, links, css imports, etc.I tried this: RewriteRule ^/(.*) /web/$1

Comment: Where are the other elements located? For example javascript files or images

Comment: They are all over the place, as this is a very large legacy application. I was just curious to know if we could have every reference to a resource converted from /* to /web/*

Comment: You can make a rule that change everything except web to /web/* ,somthing like this `RewriteRule ^/(?!web)(.*) /web/$2 [R]`